# What happens to an object during a pre-increment operation?

Tags: c++

I have this class, and I can't understand what happens when  ++c is created. And what return *this mean? Sorry for my English.

```
class Cls{

int i;
public:
  Cls(int i=8):i(i){cout<<'A';}
  Cls(const Cls &t):i(t.i){cout<<'B';}
  ~Cls(){cout<<'C';}
  void af(){cout<<i;}
  Cls operator+(Cls &t){return Cls(i+t.i);}
  Cls operator++(){i++; return *this;}
  Cls& operator--(){--i; return *this;}
  operator int(){cout<<'D'; return i;}

  };

  int main(){

      Cls c; cout <<","; //Here the constructor will print A
      ++c; cout <<",";   // here?
      c.af(); cout <<","; //This will print 9

           //Then the destructor will print C.
      return 0;
  }
```

The actual output is:

```
A,BC,9,C
```

I expect that it should print:

```
A,,9,C
```

Why is `BC` being printed?

Comment: Your choice of name makes the question a bit confusing. I first thought you were asking what happens when a c++ object is created.

Comment: `this` is know as the "this pointer".

Comment: ++c is _created_?

Comment: `++c` is the call of the post-increment operator (that has been overloaded in your code) on the object of class `Cls`. That method returns `*this` so you can chain multiple methods. `this` is a pointer to the calling object, so `*this` is the object itself

Comment: The question's not clear - please see [ask].

Comment: `return *this` means "return me!" in C++ terms.

Comment: My question is: WHY ++C; print out  BC??

Comment: @Shadow because when you return by value copy constructor was involved and temporary destroyed.

Comment: Change `Cls operator++()` to `Cls& operator++()`, which you clearly know is different, as you did so in your decrement operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-increment operator method returns a **new** object.  Which invokes a constructor and, shortly later, destructor.

```
Cls operator++(){i++; return *this;}
^^^  return by value.
     Means you need to be able to copy construct "Cls"
```

Note you would normally write this as:

```
Cls& operator++(){i++; return *this;}
  ^^^   To return the object by reference (and thus avoid construction/destruction).
```

You should also note that if you increase the optimization level you are using then the "BC" are likely to disappear as the compiler can easily "elide" the copy operation as an optimization.